Proving inequality where $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 =3$ and $a,b,c$ are positive reals

For $a,b,c >0 $ and given $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 =3 $ prove the following
inequality:
$\large a+b+c +\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ca}{b} \leqslant
3\left( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} +\frac{c}{a} -1 \right) $
When equality occurs and why?

I've tried to multiply the inequality by $abc$
$abc(a+b+c) +(ab)^2 + (bc)^2 +(ca)^2 \leqslant 3(a^2 c +b^2 a +c^2 b -abc)$
I noted that RHS $ \ge 3(3abc-abc)=6abc$
I don't think $6abc \ge (ab)^2 +(bc)^2 + (ca)^2 +abc(a+b+c) $ suffices or works or whatever, this is just not the right track.
Anyone take the lead ?

A well-known algebraic identity:
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)\geq0\tag{1}$$
So, $$ab+bc+ca\leq a^2+b^2+c^2=3\tag{2}$$
Also, $$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)\leq3+2\cdot3=9\implies a+b+c\leq3\tag{3}$$
And, $$abc\leq1\tag{4}$$
Now,
$$\begin{aligned}3\left(\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca\right)-\left(a+b+c+\frac{ab}c+\frac{bc}a+\frac{ca}b\right)&\geq(3-c)\frac{a}{b}+(3-a)\frac{b}{c}+(3-b)\frac{c}{a}-3\\&\geq3\sqrt[3]{(3-c)\frac{a}{b}\cdot(3-a)\frac{b}{c}\cdot(3-b)\frac{c}{a}}-3\\&=3\sqrt[3]{\color{red}{27-9(a+b+c)-abc+3(ab+bc+ca)}}-3\\&\geq3\sqrt[3]{\color{red}{27-9\cdot3-1+3\cdot3}}-3\\&=3\sqrt[3]{8}-3\\&=3\\a+b+c +\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ca}{b} &\leq
3\left( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} +\frac{c}{a} -1 \right)\qquad\text{proved.}
\end{aligned}$$
The equality occurs when $a=b=c=1$, for which $a+b+c=3=ab+bc+ca=3abc$.
Clarification: Both $\color{red}{a+b+c}$ and $\color{red}{ab+bc+ca}$ have maximum values of $3$. There is a higher coefficient $(9)$ of $a+b+c$ compared to the coefficient of $ab+bc+ca$, which is $3$, i.e. $9(a+b+c)$ dominates $3(ab+bc+ca)$. There is also a negative of $abc$. So, the maximum value of $\color{red}{a+b+c}$ and $\color{red}{abc}$ gives the minimum value of the expression $\color{red}{27-9(a+b+c)-abc+3(ab+bc+ca)}$.

As you've mentioned, this inequality is equivalent to $$abc\sum\limits_{cyc}a+\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab)^2\leq 3\bigg(\big(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c\big)-abc\bigg)$$
The left hand side has a degree of 4, while the right hand side has a degree of 3. Therefore, we take the square of both sides, and we have $$\bigg(abc\sum\limits_{cyc}a+\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab)^2\bigg)^2\leq 9\bigg(\big(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c\big)-abc\bigg)^2=3\bigg(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2\bigg)\bigg(\big(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c\big)-abc\bigg)^2$$
Using Mathematica, \begin{aligned}&3\bigg(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2\bigg)\bigg(\big(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c\big)-abc\bigg)^2-\bigg(abc\sum\limits_{cyc}a+\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab)^2\bigg)^2 \\=&4\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3b^2c(a-b)^2+3\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2b^4(b-c)^2+2abc\sum\limits_{cyc}\bigg(a^4b-a^2bc^2\bigg)+2\sum\limits_{cyc}\bigg(a^4b^4-a^3b^3c^2\bigg)\end{aligned}
It's easy to verify $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc}\bigg(a^4b-a^2bc^2\bigg)$ and $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc}\bigg(a^4b^4-a^3b^3c^2\bigg)$ are both non-negative. Then we're done.

I think one of the difficulties is that when tackling $$abc\sum\limits_{cyc}a+\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab)^2\leq 3\bigg(\big(\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c\big)-abc\bigg),$$ the term $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c$ is not symmetric but only cyclic. Therefore, my attempt is to find a lower bound in a both symmetric and cyclic form for $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c$.
Consider the Cauchy inequality, we have $$\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c\sum\limits_{cyc}a\geq \bigg(\sum\limits_{cyc}ab\bigg)^2.$$ Then we can use the so-called SPQ method to solve this problem. Let $\displaystyle S=\sum\limits_{cyc}a,\;P=abc,\;Q=\sum\limits_{cyc}ab$. Then we have $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc}a^2c\geq \frac{Q^2}{S}$, and $\displaystyle abc\sum\limits_{cyc}a+\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab)^2=PS+Q^2-2PS=Q^2-PS$, and therefore we need only to prove $$Q^2-PS\leq 3\bigg(\frac{Q^2}{S}-P\bigg),$$ which is equivalent to $\displaystyle Q^2(3-S)\geq SP(3-S)$. Since $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc}a^2=S^2-2Q=3$ and $S^2\geq 3Q$ (this can be easily proved), we have $9=3(S^2-2Q)\geq S^2$, which implies $S\leq 3$. Then we need only to prove $Q^2\geq SP$, which is always true (in fact it can be easily shown that $Q^2\geq 3PS$).
